# How to post body in sitebricks-client?

Tags: java, rest, post, rest-client, sitebricks

I am using [sitebricks-client](http://sitebricks.org/#webclient) to interact with REST APIs in Java. I need to do a POST with a non-empty body. How do I do that in sitebricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified what kind of request body you are trying to post. If you are trying to send a String with a Content-Type of "text/plain", then the following should work:

```
String body = "Request body.";
WebResponse response = web.clientOf(url)
    .transports(String.class)
    .over(Text.class)
    .post(body);
```

If you are trying to send data of a particular type that you have already serialized to a String, you can set the Content-Type header manually:

```
String body = "{}";
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
WebResponse response = web.clientOf(url, headers)
    .transports(String.class)
    .over(Text.class)
    .post(body);
```

If you have a Map containing data that you would like to send to the server with a Content-Type of "application/json", then something like this might be up your alley:

```
Map body = new HashMap();
// Fill in body with data
WebResponse response = web.clientOf(url)
    .transports(Map.class)
    .over(Json.class)
    .post(body);
```

There are two important points to pay attention to in the examples above:

- The value passed to the `post` method should be of the type passed to the `transports` method.
- The class that you pass to the `over` method determines the default value of the Content-Type header and the way in which the value passed to the `post` method is serialized. The class should be a subclass of `com.google.sitebricks.client.Transport`, and you will probably want to choose one of the classes found in the `com.google.sitebricks.client.transport` package.

Answer (score 0):

I have note tried it but there is a post() method in webclient.

```
web.clientOf("http://google.com")
...
.post(...);
```

Check out the source on github

https://github.com/dhanji/sitebricks/blob/master/sitebricks-client/src/main/java/com/google/sitebricks/client/WebClient.java

Rgds

Comment: There is a `POST` method but I don't see how it allows me to set the body of the request which my original question asks - how to do a `POST` with non-empty body